# AngularJS moving ui-view breaks rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, jhipster

I am developing an angularJS site using the jhipster framework. The framework provides a AngularJS + Bootstrap + Spring Boot combination. I have been trying to replace bootstrap by angular material but I am having trouble doing so.

Original index.html setup:

```
<div ui-view="navbar" ng-cloak=""></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="well" ui-view="content"></div>
</div>
```

Both the navbar and content ui-view map to a view:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
$stateProvider.state('site', {
            'abstract': true,
            views: {
                'navbar@': {
                    templateUrl: 'scripts/components/navbar/navbar.html',
                    controller: 'NavbarController'
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                authorize: ['Auth',
                    function (Auth) {
                        return Auth.authorize();
                    }
                ],
                translatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
                    $translatePartialLoader.addPart('global');
                }]
            }
        });


$stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                parent: 'site',
                url: '/',
                data: {
                    authorities: []
                },
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl: 'scripts/app/main/main.html',
                        controller: 'MainController'
                    }
                },
                resolve: {
                    mainTranslatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($translate,$translatePartialLoader) {
                        $translatePartialLoader.addPart('main');
                        return $translate.refresh();
                    }]
                }
            });
```

I would like to render my content within my navbar view because that is how the angular material side navigation component works: http://codepen.io/marcysutton/pen/OPbpKm, this is where my trouble starts.

If I move the content ui-view into to correct part of the navbar nothing gets renderder

new navbar.html:

```
...
</md-sidenav>
<div layout="column" flex id="content">
    <md-content layout="column" flex class="md-padding">
        <div class="well" ui-view="content"></div>
    </md-content>
</div>
...
```

Do I need to change something in my angular code to support this behavior? Thanks in advance! NOTE: the original index.html works, fails after moving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by doing the following:

```
 views: {
     'content@site': {
     ...
```